# MODIFY COLUMN error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql script that creates a table in my MySql database.

```
CREATE TABLE USER_ACCOUNT
(ID             DECIMAL(10)     NOT NULL,
 USERNAME       VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
 PASSWORD       VARCHAR (25)    NOT NULL,
 EMAIL          VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
 FIRST_NAME     VARCHAR (25)    NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 MIDDLE_NAME    VARCHAR (25)    NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 LAST_NAME      VARCHAR (25)    NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 CREATE_DATE    TIMESTAMP       NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

ALTER TABLE USER_ACCOUNT
  ADD CONSTRAINT USER_ACCOUNT_PK_ID
      PRIMARY KEY (ID);

ALTER TABLE USER_ACCOUNT
  ADD CONSTRAINT USER_ACCOUNT_UK_USERNAME
      UNIQUE (USERNAME);

ALTER TABLE USER_ACCOUNT 
  MODIFY COLUMN ID DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I understand that `AUTO_INCREMENT` has to be added to a `KEY`. I am trying to add `AUTO_INCREMENT` to the primary key `ID` but the line

```
ALTER TABLE USER_ACCOUNT 
  MODIFY COLUMN ID DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Has the following syntax error:

```
Syntax error: unexpected 'DECIMAL' (decimal)
```

And then has this error when the script is run:

```
Error Code: 1063. Incorrect column specifier for column 'ID'
```

What's going on with my statement? I've looked all over online and it looks like the correct syntax.

Comment: Most probably the error has to do with `DECIMAL` data type. I don't think you can apply `AUTO_INCREMENT` to a column of this type. Try `BIGINT` instead.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Tried it and I get the same error with `BIGINT`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Actually, my mistake, it still shows the syntax error in the MySQL Workbench but when I run the script there are no errors and everything works fine. So that was the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Graham You should accept a correct answer, so other people can find the solution.

Comment: @Scoutman I see you changed your answer to what GiorgosBetsos said.... fish much?

Comment: Haha very funny :-P You wrote about a syntax error also with bigint. So I updates my answer to show you a solution. That was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what Giorgos Betsos mentioned in the comments above, I changed `DECIMAL(10)` to `BIGINT` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use for the ID integer datatype.

```
ALTER TABLE `user_account` CHANGE `ID` `ID` BIGINT  NOT NULL ;
ALTER TABLE `user_account` CHANGE `ID` `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

---

For auto increment you have to use a **integer data type**: TINYINT, SMALLINT, MEDIUMINT, INT, BIGINT

A typical data type for a index is INT or BIGINT.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 0):

If possible with out data loss, `DROP` this column and add new columns with your required attributes,

to my experience, altering PK column always teases  :(